# how to use traceability data

Tags: traceability

i've found many publications that talks about to find Traceability Links and how store them into matrix or other data structure like XML. 
I'd like to know if you know any publication on how traceability links are used.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Karl Wiegers, Software Requirements 2nd edition, Microsoft Press, p. 357 f.

ISBN 978-0-7356-1879-4

Wiegers emphasizes the use of traceability links in

- Certification of software
- Change impact analysis
- Maintenance
- Project tracking
- Reengineering
- Reuse
- Riskreduction
- Testing

Answer (score 3):

A high level (i.e. short) answer is given on the german wikipedia:

> With the help of traceabilty data it is possible to measure the quality and progress in a systems development project. This is espicially relevant for the development of security critical systems, as legal requirements such as ISO 26262 or Automotive Spice require traceability to proof that security critical requirements have been implemented and tested in adequate quality. Furthermore, traceability makes impact analysis easy.

refer to https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%BCckverfolgbarkeit_(Anforderungsmanagement)

Fore a more commercial view, you may want to look at the benefits promised by dedicated traceability tools, such as

> Validate your links and requirements after every change to be sure to achieve consistent traceability and unsuspicous links.

or

> Visualize artifacts and their relations for a clear overview. Navigate between interrelated artifacts with a simple mouse-click and analyze their dependencies.

(In this case cited from https://www.itemis.com/en/yakindu/traceability/ )